# How can I remaster a text-based linux distro?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-distributions

So I have a Ubuntu minimal install, it is exactly the way I want it when I want to have a fresh install, with the included settings, packages, etc.

It has no desktop, it is completely CLI.

What is an easy way to take the current state that it is in, and make it into a live CD with an installer to an HD? I tried remastersys, but it isnt compatible with Ubuntu CLI, and I'm not fond of the settings remastersys leaves behind.

Any suggestions?

Comment: While this question is perfectly on topic here, you might get better answers on such a technical Linux question at [Unix&Linux.se](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). _If_ you want it migrated, you can use the `flag` link above to ask a moderator to move it for you. You don't _have_ to, the choice is completely up to you.